# Difference between "purpose" and "goal"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, synonyms, translation

What does this sentence from *Star Trek: The Alternative Factor* mean?

> Jim, madness has no **purpose** ... or reason ... but it may have a
>   **goal**.

As far as I know *purpose* and *goal* are synonyms. How about this case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A goal is a concrete eventuality you're trying to accomplish, while purpose implies a broader, more abstract teleological drive.  The speaker is basically saying that crazy people may be trying to do something, they just aren't doing it for a reason.  Which is ridiculous, but sounds portentous when you formulate it bombastically enough.

Comment: Put more simply, a goal is something you're trying to do, while a purpose is the reason you're trying to do it. Goal answers the question, "What?" while purpose answers the question, "Why?"

Comment: Agree. I guess I'd have to watch the movie to get the context. But just because a "purpose" or "reason" seems irrational to me doesn't mean it doesn't exist. Like if someone says, "I wear a tinfoil hat to prevent the aliens from using their mind control rays on me," he clearly has a purpose and a reason for his actions. They're just loony. (Or maybe I just think it's crazy because that's what the mind control rays tell me to think ...)

Comment: *sounds portentous when you formulate it bombastically enough.*  This reminds me of people coming here to ask what Yoda means by his pronouncements in the Star Wars movies.

Answer (score 4):

I think of purpose and goal this way:

> Our ***goal*** is to get in and get out without being seen.
> Our ***purpose*** is to rescue the prisoner.
>
> My ***goal*** is to get to the finish line first.
> My ***purpose*** is to win the race.

Answer (score 1):

**Goal** is something considered worth achieving, as an 'object': «*[...] but winning is an object (= a **goal**) [...]*».

I think that in the following sentences the word 'goal' cannot be replaced with 'purpose'.

> The Third Reich was a *sui generis* horror: a state resting on
>   systematic mass murder as a central ***goal***.
>
> Define your ***goals*** before investing.
>
> ***Goal*** line.

On the other hand, in the following sentences the word 'purpose' cannot be replaced with 'goal'.

> For rhetorical ***purposes***, logic is essential.
>
> The preferred form for ordinary ***purpose*** [...].

Conclusively, the difference is actually a shade: the ***goal**** gives the idea of something that have been set, something specific, say the "specific purpose" of a study of a mission, etc., but ***purpose*** have a little more general connotations.

* <sub>*Useful mnemonic: Goal is SMART (S:  Specific;  M:  Measurable;  A:  Attainable;  R:  Realistic;  T:  reached in a finite period of Time.)*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I believe the goal was to say that madness may lead to actions meant to achieve something which a person cannot understand in a sane context. No purpose or reason - as in "something understandable to a sane person" - but a goal, as in Silence of the Lambs, to become a woman by making a woman suit out of skin flayed from murder victims.

To a sane person, this is obviously not going to work, so there's no (sane) purpose; there's no provable chain of logic that demonstrates it's effective: no (sane) reason; but the serial killer is trying to do it nonetheless: a goal.

Answer (score 0):

I believe  goal is desired result that you try to do whereas purpose is refes to reason why u want to achive result or a reason of doing something to achive

Comment: Welcome to the ELU :-). Opinion-based replies are more suitable for comments; an [answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) would usually contain references where possible. Also, since this is a website dedicated to language, proper spelling is desirable, at least in the answers. Thanks!