# Is there a difference between "purpose" and "objective" and "scope"

Tags: meaning

I'm reading an IT book. It says the `purpose` of the "activity X" is to do this... And the `objective` of the "activity X" is to do that... Finally the `scope` of "activity X" is this, this, and that....

I'm not a native speaker so I was wondering if there was a difference between those three words (especially for British people since it's a British book I'm reading

[Link showing where instances of those words are seen in the context I'm studying](https://www.axelos.com/corporate/media/files/syllabi/the_itil_foundation_certificate_syllabus_v5-5.pdf)

Why am I having a problem to understand this ?
I went of the website `wordreference.com` but the translation given for these words are the same. In french they mean `objectif` and this is the first translation/meaning for all of them.

[scope in french](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/scope)

[objective in french](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/objective)

[purpose in french](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/purpose)

Comment: Welcome, Jason. Could you please tell us if you have done any preliminary research, namely looking up these three words in a dictionary? If you have, you should summarize what you found and what you still don't understand. Please see [this topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) at the Help Center.

Comment: @vpn  Yes. I forgot to add that. I've updated my OP

Comment: Purpose is ***why*** you are doing it. Objective is ***what*** you hope to accomplish.  And scope is the ***breadth*** of what is being addressed.

Comment: @Jim: Nice succinct explanation, that should be an answer instead of just a comment imho.

Comment: @ Jim Very nice. @

Comment: Jim's is a very nice explanation. IT people in the US are notorious for being (generally) poor at English. So purpose = raison, objective = but, scope = champ.

Comment: @JeffMorrow I suppose you speak french. I'm stiil confused as raison and but are synonym

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between "purpose" and "goal"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63831/difference-between-purpose-and-goal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they're not the same. Just based on your own research links from the EN->FR reference, in this context you can see that:

- Purpose is a **reason** to do something
- Objective is a **goal** that you're trying to achieve
- Scope is the **extent** of your work towards it

To use all 3 in a sentence together:

> You are studying within the *scope/extent* of the given syllabus for the *purpose/reason* of acquiring the certificate which is your *objective/goal*.

In the above sentence, 'objective of acquiring certificate' is a valid phrase so it is a bit confusing. Consider the below sentence I got from Google autocomplete:

> What **purpose** do committees serve in Congress?

This question is asking about the reason or justification for creating committees, not their goals (objectives) that they might be working on.

Interestingly, I found it hard to think of a non-question where purpose is used in the context where objective won't fit - looks like a 'reason' to act is always towards a 'goal'!

Comment: This is exactly why I'm confused. You said " for the purpose/reason of acquiring the certificate which is your objective/goal " So the reason is the objective.... So it's the same thing !? Reason/purpose and goal/objective looks like synonym words

Comment: @JasonKrs: a goal here is a "prize," be it physical such as a diploma or just satisfaction.  The "purpose" is that you want to get the prize.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Thanks Carl.  Am I right to say : One wants to satisfy his/her purpose by accomplishing the activities of the objectives (or simply by accomplishing the objectives).  So the objectives are the activities to be carried out in order to reach a purpose ?

Comment: @JasonKrs  close... Try to think of "purpose" more as "motivation" than "final goal"